# VMware Tanzu (former PCF) App Autoscaler force scale-down?

Tags: vmware, cloud-foundry, pcf

I am autoscaling my application based on the HTTP throughput.

My question here is when it reaches min threshold it tries to reduce the instance created. But during reducing the instance count if my instance is running or it is processing prev HTTP request.

In this case, it will wait till the processing completes or it forcibly reduces the instance count when reached threshold.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question and as far as I understood from [App Container Lifecycle](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/app-lifecycle.html) it’s up to your app to gracefully shutdown but that might not be possible in given 10 seconds as some processes might take longer.

> **Shutdown**
> CF requests a shutdown of your app instance in the following scenarios:
> When a user runs **cf scale**, cf stop, cf push, cf delete, or cf restart-app-instance
> As a result of a system event, such as the replacement procedure during Diego Cell evacuation or when an app instance stops because of a failed health check probe
> To shut down the app, CF sends the app process in the container a SIGTERM. By default, the process has ten seconds to shut down gracefully. If the process has not exited after ten seconds, CF sends a SIGKILL.
> By default, apps must finish their in-flight jobs within ten seconds of receiving the SIGTERM before CF terminates the app with a SIGKILL. For instance, a web app must finish processing existing requests  and stop accepting new requests.
> Note: One exception to the cases mentioned above is when monit restarts a crashed Diego Cell rep or Garden server. In this case, CF immediately stops the apps that are still running using SIGKILL.

Answer (score 0):

> "*In this case it will wait till the processing completes or it
> forcibly reduces the instance count when reached threshold.*"

**Answer:**
No, the App Autoscaler will not force anything, after the decision cycle, it will prepare the instance to be escalated-down (shutdown), so the intention is to avoid lose requests or data during this process.

Please, take a look into the documentation below, it will help you to understand better the App Autoscaler mechanism.

---

**How App Autoscaler Determines When to Scale:**

> Every 35 seconds, App Autoscaler makes a decision about whether to
> scale up, scale down, or keep the same number of instances.

> To make a scaling decision, App Autoscaler averages the values of a
> given metric for the most recent 120 seconds.

The following diagram provides an example of how App Autoscaler makes scaling decisions:
[image]

**Reference:**
[VMWare Tanzu App Autoscaler documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/platform/application-service/2-10/appsman-services/autoscaler/about-app-autoscaler.html)

*VMWare Tanzu is the former Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF).*